# Geany gives error message on compiling: "Fatal: Can't find unit system used by HelloWorld"

Tags: compiling, geany

I have installed Free Pascal Compiler and Geany on my ubuntu machine. When I compile a programm with fp of FPC all is fine. If I compile the same program with Geany I get the error message "Fatal: Can't find unit system used by HelloWorld".
I already uninstalled and reinstalled FPC anf Geany several times even with the purge command but nothing changed.
On another ubuntu machine this works fine. I cannot find the mistake I made. Does anybody know how to fix this error in order to be able to compile programmes with Geany directly?
Thanks for any help.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic

Comment: This programming question belongs and has an answer on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62897801/10477326

Comment: Thank you. However, this solution relates to the problem that fpc is not installed correctly. In the present case fpc is working correctly. I  can compile programms edited with the FP-Editor. However, I want to write programs in the Geany-Editor and Geany refuses to compile with the error message mentioned above.